# QueryExpression with no results in Dynamics CRM plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, query-expressions

I wrote the following function to get the SharePointDocumentLocation records regarding an account or contact. However, even though I provide an id which most definitely has got a SPDL record associated the result of a count on the EntityCollection that is returned is alway 0. Why does my query not return SPDL records?

```
internal static EntityCollection GetSPDocumentLocation(IOrganizationService service, Guid id)
{
    SharePointDocumentLocation spd = new SharePointDocumentLocation();
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = "sharepointdocumentlocation",
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("sharepointdocumentlocationid"),
        Criteria = new FilterExpression
        {
            Conditions = 
            { 
                new ConditionExpression
                {
                    AttributeName = "regardingobjectid",
                    Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                    Values = { id }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
}
```

The following code does work

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace CRMConsoleTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            Uri orgUri = new Uri("http://localhost/CRMDEV2/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
            Uri homeRealmUri = null;
            using (OrganizationServiceProxy service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null))
            {
                //ConditionExpression ce = new ConditionExpression("regardingobjectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, new Guid(""));
                QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("sharepointdocumentlocation");
                qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new String[] { "sharepointdocumentlocationid", "regardingobjectid" });
                //qe.Criteria.AddCondition(ce);

                EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);

                foreach (Entity entity in result.Entities)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Results for the first record: ");
                    SharePointDocumentLocation spd = entity.ToEntity<SharePointDocumentLocation>();
                    if (spd.RegardingObjectId != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Id: " + spd.SharePointDocumentLocationId.ToString() + " with RoId: " + spd.RegardingObjectId.Id.ToString());
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It retrieves 4 records, and when I debug the plugincode above it retrieves 3 records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything looks good with your `QueryExpression`, although I'd write it a little more concise (something like this):

```cs
var qe = new QueryExpression(SharePointDocumentLocation.EntityLogicalName){
    ColmnSet = new ColumnSet("sharepointdocumentlocationid"),
};
qe.Criteria.AddCondition("regardingobjectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, id);
```

Because I don't see anything wrong with the `QueryExpression` that leads me with two guesses.

1. You're using impersonation on the `IOrganizationService` and the impersonated user doesn't have rights to the `SharePointDocumentLocation`.  You won't get an error, you just won't get any records returned.
2. The id you're passing in is incorrect.

I'd remove the `Criteria` and see how many records you get back.  If you don't get all of the records back, you know your issue is with guess #1.

If you get all records, add the `regardingobjectid` to the `ColumnSet` and retrieve the first record without any `Criteria` in the `QueryExpression`, then call this method passing in the id of the `regardingobject` you returned.  If nothing is received when adding the `regardingobjectid` constraint, then something else is wrong.

### Update

Since this is executing within the delete of the plugin, it must be performing its cascade deletes before your plugin is firing.  You can [try the Pre-Validation](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b05fe66-cac0-4e0c-b5f2-505b79d0d74b/crm-2011-bug-plugin-delete-message?forum=crm).

Now that I think of it, it must perform the deletion of the cascading entities in the Validation stage, because if one of them is unable to be deleted, the entity itself can't be deleted.

Comment: Hi Daryl. I tried removing the condition, it gives me the total number of SharePointDocumentLocation records. So that means I am having the correct rights. I'll try and dubbelcheck if the id is right now.

Comment: Hi Daryl. I debugged some more. Stranged thing. I have 3 accounts with a documentlocation record associated. Let's say account GUID's: ACC1, ACC2 and ACC3. If I provide the GUID ACC1, the entitycollection that is returned without the conditionoperator is three accounts, with GUID's ACC2, ACC3 and an unknown GUID. If I provide the GUID ACC2, the entitycollection that is returned has GUID's ACC1, ACC3 and the same unkown GUID. I am really lost!?

Comment: Some additional information: The function is called from a plugin Delete PreOperation event. Maybe the system returns some entity reference id when it is in the transaction?

Comment: @MartijnBurger Pull your logic out of a plugin and into a command line app, just to prove that it is plugin related.  Also, when entity is the Delete PreOperation happening on?

Comment: Good tip Daryl. I am going to try that. The delete is on the account identity. I am trying to identify all sharepointdocumentlocation records associated with the account that is deleted.

Comment: @MartijnBurger and do what with them?  Assign them to a different Account?

Comment: Daryl, definitely must be the plugin. I posted the console code above, works like a charm. Any Ideas?

Comment: @MartijnBurger how is the relationship setup?  Cascading Deletes?

Comment: Yes it is cascading deletes, that's the standard setup. Cannot be customized either. I was thinking that it was pre-operation so the spdoclocs should not have been deleted at that point. Right? I'll try and build it pre-validation, let's see how that goes.

Comment: Registering PreValidat works. Problem solved, so that's a green tick. However, an explanation why would be nice. :s